# PHP MongoDate: Invalid output with MongoDate->toDateTime()

Tags: php, mongodb, datetime, mongodate

I have a strange error with MongoDate.

First: The system is a virtual machine on a mac server.

Linux vm 3.16.0-33-generic #44~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 13 10:32:52 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

```
<?php

    $n = 1420124400;
    echo $n."\n";

    $d = new MongoDate($n);
    var_dump( $d );
    var_dump( $d->toDateTime() );
    var_dump( new DateTime("@".$d->sec) );
?>
```

I got this result:

```
object(MongoDate)#1 (2) {
  ["sec"]=>
  int(1420124400)
  ["usec"]=>
  int(0)
}
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "1969-12-14 12:37:05"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+00:00"
}
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2015-01-01 15:00:00"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+00:00"
}
```

The second dump shows the invalid date, generated by MongoDate->toDateTime(). The date value stored in the datetime object is before 1970.

Thank you,

Patrick

Comment: Hi, I encounter exactly the same problem with PHP 5.6 64 bits version and Windows 10. MongoDate->sec is valid but MongoDate->toDateTime() isn't. Did you find any reason why toDateTime() output is invalid ?